# $dr$ in polar co-ordinates

Tags: vectors, polar-coordinates

I realise $$dr = dx\hat{i} +dy\hat{j}$$

I'm trying to work out $dr$ in polar co-ordinates.

At first thought $$dx = drcos(\theta)$$

This is of course wrong as I realised

$$ dx = drcos(\theta +d\theta)$$

I've tried using the cos addition rule

$$ dx = drcos(\theta)cos(d\theta)- drsin(\theta)sin(d\theta)$$

but unsure how to recover the result 
$$ dx = drcos(\theta)-rsin(\theta)d\theta$$

Have I made a mistake in a previous part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to find the differential for a product, use the product rule: $$\frac{d(xy)}{dz}=\frac{dx}{dz} y+\frac{dy}{dz}x$$So $$d(xy)=y\,dx+x\,dy$$So in this case, $$\begin{align}d(r\cos\theta)&=\cos\theta\,dr+r\,d(\cos\theta)\\&=\cos\theta\,dr+r\,\frac{d\cos\theta}{d\theta}\,d\theta\\&=\cos\theta\,dr-r\sin\theta\,d\theta\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks this makes it so much clearer!

Comment: Why does the product rule not involve partial derivatives since this is a multivariate situation?

Comment: @chaseryantaylor I don't know why I wrote chain rule, I meant to say product rule.

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh, I didn’t even notice! I meant to say “product rule” as well. At any rate I’m still confused.

Comment: @chaseryantaylor you could expand it in terms of partial derivatives, for example if we had to compute $$d(f(x,y)xy)=xy\,df+yf\,dx+xf\,dy\\=xy\,\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\, dy\right)+yf\,dx+xf\,dy$$ I didn't  that in this example because we just had $x$ and $y$ and there was no need to expand it.

Comment: In that case, I’ll just smile and take your word for it! (All of my multivariate calculus is self-taught.)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Then, $dx=dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta d\theta$ and  $dy=dr\sin\theta+r\cos\theta d\theta$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you want is $dr$ in *cartesian* coordinates since $dr$ in polar coordinates is just $dr$

You have 2 coordinate systems $(x,y)$ and $(r,θ)$. You can relate this systems by the transition function $Φ(r,θ)=(r\cosθ,r\sinθ)=(x,y)$ and $Φ^{-1}(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))=(r,θ)$.

This means that $dr=d(x^2+y^2)=\frac{\partial(x^2+y^2)}{\partial x}dx+ \frac{\partial(x^2+y^2)}{\partial y}dy=2xdx+2ydy$. For the sake of understanding am going to write all the relations:

- $dy=d(r\sinθ)=(\sinθ)dr+(r\cosθ)dθ$
- $dx=d(r\cosθ)=(\cosθ)dr+(-r\sinθ)dθ$
- $dθ=d(\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2})dx+(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})dy$

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't mark two as the answer however this is also very helpful

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) !